# How does the requests object find the username associated with a particular token passed through Django REST Framework TokenAuthentication

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am using the TokenAuthentication provided by Django REST Framework and following this article https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

When sending the token in the header, I am not specifying the user for which I generated the token but it is automatically picking the right user. I am wondering how is that working?

This is the call I am making (Notice I only pass the token and not the username associated with the token)

`r = requests.post(url, headers={Authentication: 'Token my_token'}, data=data)`

I am creating the token using the manage.py command passing a particular username.

Answer (score 0):

So why not just look at the implementation of `TokenAuthentication`?

If you look at the implementation, you will find the following `authenticate` method. As we can see, token is stored in the db together with an user.

`authenticate` method just retrieves and checks the token and `authenticate_credentials` actually checks the table if the token exists.

```
def authenticate(self, request):
    auth = get_authorization_header(request).split()

    if not auth or auth[0].lower() != self.keyword.lower().encode():
        return None

    if len(auth) == 1:
        msg = _('Invalid token header. No credentials provided.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)
    elif len(auth) > 2:
        msg = _('Invalid token header. Token string should not contain spaces.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    try:
        token = auth[1].decode()
    except UnicodeError:
        msg = _('Invalid token header. Token string should not contain invalid characters.')
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(msg)

    return self.authenticate_credentials(token)

def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
    model = self.get_model()
    try:
        token = model.objects.select_related('user').get(key=key)
    except model.DoesNotExist:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('Invalid token.'))

    if not token.user.is_active:
        raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed(_('User inactive or deleted.'))

    return (token.user, token)
```

Comment: I think I understand the authentication part of the process properly. I was just confused as to how does the `request.user' key get the exact user the token is associated with.